# Is it possible to install mplayer without superuser rights

Tags: software-installation

I am using the Ubuntu system and I want to install mplayer for my own use only.  Can I install it without the superuser (root) rights?

Answer (score 0):

You can download the package and extract all the files to your `$HOME` directory, but you have to configure it yourself.

```
apt-get download mplayer2
dpkg --extract mplayer2*.deb $HOME
ls -l $HOME/usr/bin/mplayer
```

So you have to set up your path to where `mplayer` is located or if you already have `$HOME/bin`, you can put it there.

To add the path:

```
echo 'export PATH=$HOME/usr/bin:$PATH' >> ~/.bashrc
```

Answer (score 0):

yes it should be possible.

In theory, you can symlink the mplayer binary file to the `bin` directory which would make it accessible throughout **your** user account.

Steps:

1. Download the zip file of mplayer, say, `mplayer-20170705.zip`
2. Launch a terminal window and run `cd $HOME` to change directory to `$HOME`.
3. Extract the zip file using `unzip mplayer-20170705.zip`.
4. Symlink the `mplayer` binary to `$HOME/bin/` using `ln -s $HOME/mplayer-20170705/mplayer $HOME/bin/`
5. Test mplayer using `mplayer` on the terminal. The mplayer window should open.

Note: I highly recommend getting mpv player which is fork on mplayer and is updated regularly. You can find it in Github.

Comment: Not everyone has `~/bin` in their path.

Comment: @Henrik since this is Ubuntu, the default `~/.profile` adds `~/bin` to the PATH if it exists.